# Reactive Extensions in C#.NET throwing a 'System.Security.VerificationException' randomly

Tags: c#, .net, caching, system.reactive

The exception message is not very helpful but here it is

> 'observableTeamMember.AssignedTaskEvents.Added' threw an exception of
>   type 'System.Security.VerificationException'
>
> Method System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.FromEventPattern: type argument
>   'Bourne.iClean.Planning.Observables.NotifyChildAddedEventArgs`1[T]'
>   violates the constraint of type parameter 'TEventArgs'.

To give you a brief overview, We have a C#.NET windows service hosted server side which deals with requests from a web application. The service queries a **'planning model'** which is a cached version of all the data objects, we maintain this cache in order to speed up responses to queries from the front end.

We are using reactive extensions to keep our data cache up to date whenever certain events occur (like updates to data objects). Some objects in the data cache have child events subscription and when any of these child objects are changed, we update the cache, for example- we have a **TeamMemberObject** as follows which has some child events associated with it

```
 public interface IObservableTeamMember : IObservableEntity<TeamMember>
{
    ChildEvents<TeamCalendar> TeamCalendarEvents {get;}
    ChildEvents<AssignedTaskTeamMember> AssignedTaskEvents { get; }
    ChildEvents<WorkplaceAssignedTaskTeamMember> WorkplaceAssignedTaskEvents { get; }
}
```

Whenever any of these child events/objects are updated, we update our cache using the following code. The block below in where I get the **security exception**

```
observableTeamMember.AssignedTaskEvents.Added.Subscribe((NotifyChildAddedEventArgs<AssignedTaskTeamMember> e) =>
        {
            this._addAssignedTaskEntry(e.AddedChild);
        });
```

I am also including partial code for the Child Event Class below

```
public class ChildEvents<T> : IChildEvents<T>
{
    public void Add(T child)
    {
        var args = new NotifyChildAddedEventArgs<T>(child);
        _raiseChildAdded(args);
    }

    public void Remove(T child)
    {
        var args = new NotifyChildDeletedEventArgs<T>(child);
        _raiseChildDeleted(args);
    }

    event NotifyChildAddedEventHandler<T> _baseTAdded;

    protected void _raiseChildAdded(NotifyChildAddedEventArgs<T> args)
    {
        var childAdded = _baseTAdded;
        if (childAdded != null)
            childAdded(this, args);
    }

    private IObservable<NotifyChildAddedEventArgs<T>> _childAdded;
    public IObservable<NotifyChildAddedEventArgs<T>> Added
    {
        get
        {
            if (_childAdded == null)
                _childAdded = Observable.FromEventPattern<NotifyChildAddedEventHandler<T>, NotifyChildAddedEventArgs<T>>(
                    (handler) => _baseTAdded += handler,
                    (handler) => _baseTAdded -= handler)
                    .Select(e => e.EventArgs);
            return _childAdded;
        }
    }
}
```

This exception only happens occasionally and we are a team of 3 and it has happened randomly to all of us at some point. We use reactive extensions throughout this project and we are unable to explain the cause. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Tapashya

Answer (score 1):

That error suggests that  your `Bourne.iClean.Planning.Observables.NotifyChildAddedEventArgs<T>` does not inherit from `System.EventArgs`, which is required by `Observable.FromEventPattern` since it specifically expects you to confirm to the standard .NET event pattern.